# Logout without confirmation and SAME window on mobile

Tags: redirect, logout

I using this code to logout. It works except on mobile it opens a new window. How can I logout with confirmation and redirect to to the same window?

```
add_action('check_admin_referer', 'logout_without_confirm', 10, 2);
function logout_without_confirm($action, $result)
{
    /**
     * Allow logout without confirmation
     */
    if ($action == "log-out" && !isset($_GET['_wpnonce'])) {
        $redirect_to = isset($_REQUEST['redirect_to']) ? $_REQUEST['redirect_to'] : 'https://www.example.com';
        $location = str_replace('&amp;', '&', wp_logout_url($redirect_to));
        header("Location: $location");
        die;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using wp_redirect($url). See https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_redirect/ .

So...something like:

```
// set up the URL to redirect to
$redirect_to = 'https://www.example.com/page';
wp_redirect($redirect_to);
exit;
```

Note that exit is required to close out the code. See the docs in the above link.